# Uniswap v3 custom ERC20 token swap

Tags: ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts, uniswap

I am trying to implement a token swap of my custom ERC20 token via UniswapV3

I use Rinkeby Ethereum network.

I deployed the token under address: `0x4646CB39EA04d4763BED770F80F0e0dE8efcdF0f`

I added the liquidity to Uniswap for this token and ETH.

Now, I try to execute swap in my contract, but it doesn't work. I get the error:

```
Gas estimation errored with the following message (see below). The transaction execution will likely fail. Do you want to force sending?
execution reverted
```

My `Swap.sol` contract takes an address of the token to swap with ETH as a constructor parameter. When I deploy it using DAI token address, the swap works just fine.

I assume this is a Uniswap liquidity related problem, but I added liquidity manually and I can swap my token inside their app.

Contract code:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.10;
pragma abicoder v2;

import "@uniswap/v3-periphery/contracts/libraries/TransferHelper.sol";
import "@uniswap/v3-periphery/contracts/interfaces/ISwapRouter.sol";
import "@uniswap/v3-periphery/contracts/interfaces/IQuoter.sol";


contract Swap {
    address private constant SWAP_ROUTER =
        0xE592427A0AEce92De3Edee1F18E0157C05861564;
    address private constant WETH = 0xc778417E063141139Fce010982780140Aa0cD5Ab;
    address public tokenAddress;

    address public immutable _owner;
    ISwapRouter public immutable swapRouter;

    constructor(address token) {
        _owner = msg.sender;
        swapRouter = ISwapRouter(SWAP_ROUTER);
        tokenAddress = token;
    }

    function swapExactInputSingle() external payable {
        require(msg.value > 0, "Must pass non 0 ETH amount");
        ISwapRouter.ExactInputSingleParams memory params = ISwapRouter
            .ExactInputSingleParams({
                tokenIn: WETH,
                tokenOut: tokenAddress,
                fee: 3000,
                recipient: msg.sender,
                deadline: block.timestamp,
                amountIn: msg.value,
                amountOutMinimum: 1,
                sqrtPriceLimitX96: 0
            });

        swapRouter.exactInputSingle{value: msg.value}(params);
    }

    receive() external payable {}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue with the swapExactInputMultihop function on uniswap. For each pools/paths you're going through, you need to make sure you've got the correct pool fee set.

You can checkout the swap fees on the uniswap website: [V3-overview/fees](https://docs.uniswap.org/protocol/concepts/V3-overview/fees)

or on a video tutorial, going through the whole process:
[**Blockchain With Wisdom** on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RZuAUbNGkD0)

Answer (score 0):

Managed to fix it.

I set the `fee: 3000` in contract, but I created liquidity with 1% fee, so I had to change it to `fee: 10000` according to docs: `fee The fee tier of the pool, used to determine the correct pool contract in which to execute the swap`